# Subview of UIButton needs releasing?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, release, subview, autorelease

First time asking a question here.

I have a question, I have a `UIImageView` added as a subview to my `UIButton`, which is declared using `buttonWithType:` (which means I don't have to release the button right?) But do I still have to release the subview of my `UIButton`?

Code bits:

```
UIImage *circleImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"item-circle" ofType: @"png"]];
UIImageView *circleImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: circleImage] autorelease];
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(-5, -5, 65, 65)];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addSubview: circleImageView];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to mark answers as correct and pay attention to the way questions are asked.

Comment: Thanks :) Oops noticed that I already autoreleased the UIImageView, so that works right?

Comment: Your code is good, `circleImageView` will be retained by `button` until button is released, but you don't need to worry about any of it as the only object you allocated has been marked for autorelease anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Your code seems fine. The basic rule of thumb is that for every `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`, you need a `release` or `autorelease`.

---

**Long Answer:**

Let's go through your code line by line.

```
UIImage *circleImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource: @"item-circle" ofType: @"png"]];
```

This first line uses a convenience method. you don't need to call release on anything, since you haven't called `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`.

```
UIImageView *circleImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: circleImage] autorelease];
```

In the second line, you call `alloc`, but you then call `autoerelease`, so you're good there.

```
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(-5, -5, 65, 65)];
```

Again, no `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Once again, you've used a convenience method.

```
[button addSubview: circleImageView];
```

You still haven't called `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`. Therefore, you don't call `release` or `autorelease`.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, anything you `alloc` or `retain` yourself will need to be released.  But you are doing that here (in essence) by calling `autorelease`.  If you're asking whether or not you need to release the subview again, the answer is no.

The same applies to your button.  You haven't called `alloc` or `retain` (instead you used `buttonWithType`), so you don't need to call `release` on it.